# PyPdf2 interactive form elements missing after Adobe sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, itext, pypdf, adobe-sign

I have an Acroform pdf that contains a combination of text and interactive fields like dropdowns and checkboxes. I am using PyPDF2 to successfully retrieve all the field values (using get_Fields() and decrypting it with the default '' password), however once the pdf is signed using Acrobat Sign, I cannot access the interactive fields anymore. I read on another SO post that signing a pdf flattens it, however I can still access all the text fields after signing.

I have tried both PyPDF2 and the java RUPS iText 5.5.9 desktop app, and neither of them can see any interactive fields (dropdowns, checkboxes, datepickers) after signing the pdf. Is there a way to read interactive fields at all after signing?

Thank you.

Comment: Unclear to me what you mean by "interactive fields" are no longer accessible, but text fields still are: they are *interactive* too, aren't they?

Comment: Quote: "the java iText desktop app"
Do you mean RUPS?

Comment: @JorjMcKie Sorry if it was unclear. The form has a combination of text fields, datepickers, dropdowns and checkboxes. Once the form is signed, I can still access the text fields programmatically, but cannot access the other types. Its as if they do not exist anymore (flattened?)

Comment: @JohanP Yes, I used the RUPS iText 5.5.9 jar file to inspect the file, when I couldnt access it through the PyPdf2 python library.